# PHP CMS URL Pattern Matching

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

As mentioned in the title, I'm building a CMS and I'm trying to work Patterned URLs into the system.
As part of this, Modules can be assigned to a base handle, then have parameters passed to it.

Using a regular expression I'd like to match URLs and be able to extract the wildcard information from them.
The general format is below.

```
http://i3network.net/module/
http://i3network.net/module/action/
http://i3network.net/module/action/id/
http://i3network.net/module/action/id/subaction/
```

I'm currently running this by having 4 regular expressions for each module (that has this feature enabled) are loaded from the database and individually checked.

The problem that I'm having is that the expressions are matching the first, then not continuing through the order.

This is the expression that I'm using at the moment for the first level.

```
/^module\//
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of regex, why not just `explode('/', $uri)` and extract each part for the resultant array if it exists?

Comment: Are you using Apache (htaccess) to handle the redirection?

Comment: @Michael: 2 reasons; this check is done from the database, I'm pulling the expressions from the database to check them, I don't want it to always match any time an exploded point is equal to a module name.

Comment: @Ryanve This is happening well AFTER .htaccess - yes it is used to make any url point to the application, after which the application needs to determine which content to show.

Comment: @ajdi Is the problem solved? If you solved it, please post an answer. I guess it is related to the order of the regexps: you need to check against the longest one first, like [`^module\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/nNhYpA/1), proceeding to the `/^module\//` - right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm using `/^photography$/`, `/^photography\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-])*$/`, and `/^photography\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-])*\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-])*/` to confirm which module to use (with another `([a-zA-Z0-9_-])*\/` for each level deeper, then `/^photography\/(.*?)/` and `/^proofs\/(.*?)\/(.*?)/` to get the 'action' and 'id` (additionally with another `/(.*?)/` for each sub action deeper.
It's all processed in PHP - I get all expressions from the database then loop through them.

Comment: Well, I think you should post this as answer so that the question was "finalized".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using `/^photography$/`, `/^photography\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-])*$/`, and `/^photography\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-])*\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-])*/` to confirm which module to use (with another (`[a-zA-Z0-9_-])*\/` for each level deeper, then `/^photography\/(.*?)/` and `/^proofs\/(.*?)\/(.*?)/` to get the 'action' and 'id`(additionally with another`/(.*?)/` for each sub action deeper. It's all processed in PHP - I get all expressions from the database then loop through them.